# What exactly are smart material packs on Quixel Mixer?

Tags: materials

Not sure if this is a good spot to ask this, but I'm using this for Unreal, so I figure it probably is?  If not, please comment instead of downvoting.

When prompted to select the packs I wanted on the installer, I left it at the default which was only Smart Material Pack 5, mainly because it made it a 3 gb download instead of a 20 gb download.  This leads me to wonder what exactly these packs do, and what I will be missing by not downloading all of them?  Will I still get all of Mixers features?  Are they just materials with settings already set up?  Thanks.

Comment: The first hit on my search for 'quixel mixer smart packs' brings up their [blog post](https://quixel.com/blog/2020/6/22/quixel-mixer-2020-1-2-new-smart-materials-next-gen-texturing) which seems to address your questions.

Comment: The down vote guidance indicates a down vote means: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". If you are making a good faith effort to ask researched, clear questions that may have value to others, there's no need to ask the community not to downvote. If you're doing that and still attracting down votes, you might want to drop into chat to discuss the matter.  Good luck with your project.

Comment: the reason I ask people not to downvote, is because If they downvote and give absolutely no clue as to why they did, I have no idea why my question is bad, and they might even be trolling for all I know.  I've had a lot of questions downvoted for seemingly no reason (especially on the arquade site)  I do get your point though, thnx.  =)